# connecting to sql remotely with named instance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have just install mssql 2008 r2. I am unable to connect to the server remotely.

I have followed the details on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) in regards to openning the firewall and allowing remote connections. Actually for testing purposes i've disabled the firewall.

I'm getting error 26. Which refers to be unable to find the instance name.

I've tried difference variations of the following my local mssql 2008

Servername: remoteIp\instanceName

Login: myUser

Password: myPassword

If my servername correct

Comment: Make sure that "SQL Server Browser" Services is running.

Comment: Ckeck this [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1499314.aspx/1) and [videol link](http://techpint.com/programming/error-26-%E2%80%93-error-locating-serverinstance-specified-sql-server). This help me in the past..

Comment: I believe i'm compliant with the issues outlined in your link. Does my servername look correct. Should i include my remote servers computer name.

Comment: ServerName\InstanceName. you can varified the name by going to services.msc then scroll down to "SQL Server (InstanceName)" services.

Comment: so something like 37.123.123.123/myinstance should be correct?

Comment: Pleser try this 37.123.123.123\myinstance

Comment: While installing "mssql 2008 r2" what Instance name you gave?